# Selected Checkbox Choices Not Saved for Has Many Through Relationship in Rails 3

Tags: ruby-on-rails, parent-child, has-many-through

So, I have a model, Task, that is supposed to allow for parents-children relationships. These are the relevant parts of the model definition:

```
class Task < ActiveRecord::Base

  attr_accessible :relationships_attributes

  has_many :relationships, :foreign_key => "subtask_id", :dependent => :destroy
  has_many :parents, :through => :relationships, :source => "parent"

  has_many :reverse_relationships, :foreign_key => "parent_id", :class_name => "Relationship", :dependent => :destroy
  has_many :subtasks, :through => :reverse_relationships, :source => "subtask"

end
```

The definition of the Relationship model is the following:

```
class Relationship < ActiveRecord::Base

  attr_accessible :parent_id

  belongs_to :parent, :class_name => "Task"
  belongs_to :subtask, :class_name => "Task"

  validates :parent_id, presence: true
  validates :subtask_id, presence: true

end
```

What I would like to do is to modify the entries present in the underlying "relationships" database table by using a form that includes a check box, which allows for choosing/removing parent task ids for a particular task. This is the code that I have in my edit.html.erb file for the check_box_tag:

```
<p>
  <br>
  <%= f.label :parent_tasks %>
  <% for task in Task.find(:all) %>
  <div>
    <%= check_box_tag "subtask[parent_ids][]", task.id, @task.parent_ids.include?(task.id)%>
    <%= task.id %>
  </div>
  <% end %>
</p>
```

When the Save button for the form is pressed, there is no error generated, but the modifications made in the check box are not saved. The log shows these entries (it does not try to delete from/insert into the relationships table):

```
Started PUT "/dev/tasks/25" for 127.0.0.1 at 2012-04-30 14:59:13 -0400
Processing by Dev::TasksController#update as HTML
  Parameters: {"utf8"=>"✓", "authenticity_token"=>"+ShrgdwgD7G1l9iDEuCsZ84d9XCwXh01p3BwJARJScE=", "task"=>{"name"=>"task bla", "description"=>"", "project_id"=>"", "task_status_id"=>"1"}, "subtask"=>{"parent_ids"=>["19", "22"]}, "commit"=>"Save changes", "id"=>"25"}
  User Load (0.8ms)  SELECT "users".* FROM "users" WHERE "users"."remember_token" = 'z7IrWT7R7u7i6nhW26J2Og' LIMIT 1
  Task Load (0.3ms)  SELECT "tasks".* FROM "tasks" WHERE "tasks"."id" = $1 LIMIT 1  [["id", "25"]]
   (0.1ms)  BEGIN
   (0.1ms)  COMMIT
Redirected to http://localhost:3000/dev/tasks
Completed 302 Found in 8ms (ActiveRecord: 1.3ms)
```

I had previously implemented the functionality I am trying to achieve for two different models, User and Team, which had a joined model, Teams_users. This is the log for the action of successfully saving the changes to the teams_users database table:

```
Started PUT "/teams/1" for 127.0.0.1 at 2012-04-30 14:46:11 -0400
Processing by TeamsController#update as HTML
  Parameters: {"utf8"=>"✓", "authenticity_token"=>"+ShrgdwgD7G1l9iDEuCsZ84d9XCwXh01p3BwJARJScE=", "team"=>{"name"=>"My team", "user_ids"=>["3", "8", "9", "100", "101"]}, "commit"=>"Save", "id"=>"1"}
  Team Load (0.3ms)  SELECT "teams".* FROM "teams" WHERE "teams"."id" = $1 LIMIT 1  [["id", "1"]]
   (0.1ms)  BEGIN
  User Load (0.4ms)  SELECT "users".* FROM "users" WHERE "users"."id" IN (3, 8, 9, 100, 101)
  User Load (0.4ms)  SELECT "users".* FROM "users" INNER JOIN "teams_users" ON "users"."id" = "teams_users"."user_id" WHERE "teams_users"."team_id" = 1
   (0.2ms)  DELETE FROM "teams_users" WHERE "teams_users"."team_id" = 1 AND "teams_users"."user_id" IN (2, 4)
   (38.3ms)  INSERT INTO "teams_users" ("team_id", "user_id") VALUES (1, 3) RETURNING "id"
  Team Exists (0.4ms)  SELECT 1 FROM "teams" WHERE (LOWER("teams"."name") = LOWER('My team') AND "teams"."id" != 1) LIMIT 1
   (39.9ms)  COMMIT
Redirected to http://localhost:3000/teams/1
Completed 302 Found in 88ms (ActiveRecord: 81.0ms)
```

I am hoping that the required modifications to get my current code working are small and that someone will be able to point me to them or to some relevant posts that I have not yet run into :).